# Freeform email validation possible?

Tags: solspace-freeform

By that I mean can an email field be presented twice on a form and the entry have to match before form submission is allowed?

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the documentation here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#matching_fields